# PDFTK - Unable to find input files

Tags: windows

I am trying to merge 2 pdf files using Access 2007 VBA, I have checked that all the files are in the correct place but when I do the merge PDFTK cannot find the input files. For any help or suggestions I would be most grateful.

I have copied my vba code below

```
Reportstring = ""
Reportstring = Environ("userprofile") & "\Documents\Datafiles\BatleyHousingSurveys\BookletinputFiles\1_BookletFrontPage.pdf" & " "
Reportstring = Reportstring & Environ("userprofile") & "\Documents\Datafiles\BatleyHousingSurveys\BookletinputFiles\2_BookletContentsPage.pdf" & " "
Reportstring = Reportstring + "Cat Output " + Environ("userprofile") & "\Documents\Datafiles\BatleyHousingSurveys\BookletinputFiles\HousingBooklet.pdf"

Shell (Environ("programfiles") & "\PDFtk Server\bin\PDFTK.exe " + Reportstring), 3
```

Why does it say it can't find the files?

Answer (score 0):

The path to the PDFTK executable has spaces in it.

Here is how you want the command to look:

- Executable: `C:\Program Files\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe`
- Arguments: `C:\Users\user\Documents\Datafiles\...` (not going to paste in the whole thing)

Here is what the system actually sees:

- Executable: `C:\Program`
- Arguments: `Files\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe C:\Users\user\Documents\Datafiles\...`

Of course there is no such executable as `C:\Program`, so that is the error you are getting.

You need to surround the executable name in quotation marks (`"`) to prevent the spaces from causing problems. (You should also include the filenames in quotation marks, just out of habit and good practice.)

Here is how I would probably write this code (broken into more lines so it is easier to read and easier to modify in the future):

```vb
DblQuote = """" ' This is a single (") character

BaseFilePath = Environ("userprofile") & "\Documents\Datafiles\BatleyHousingSurveys\BookletinputFiles\"

FirstFilePath = DblQuote & BaseFilePath & "1_BookletFrontPage.pdf" & DblQuote
SecondFilePath = DblQuote & BaseFilePath & "2_BookletContentsPage.pdf" & DblQuote
Operations = "cat output"
OutputFilePath = DblQuote & BaseFilePath & "HousingBooklet.pdf" & DblQuote

ArgumentString = FirstFilePath & " " & SecondFilePath & " " & Operations & " " & OutputFilePath

ExecutablePath = DblQuote & Environ("programfiles") & "\PDFtk Server\bin\PDFTK.exe" & DblQuote

Shell (ExecutablePath & " " & ArgumentString), 3
```

Comment: Is theargumentstring line correct?, in my code theline is highlighted in Red and it has a syntax error. I have defined all the variables as string

Comment: @IanC Sorry I missed one ampersand. Fixed now.

Comment: Sorry for they delay in replying, your code now works perfectly.
Thanks again for your help, it was much apreciated
Ian C

Comment: @IanC Great to hear that I could help. You should click the check-mark to mark this answer as "accepted" and it would be nice if you hit the up arrow to upvote too.